# testing a method with another method from the same class

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

Sorry ahead if this is a duplicate, but whenever I try to search this I get results about "testing method that calls other methods" which is not what I am trying to clarify.

Student here. I am wondering whether testing a method with another method from the same class is actually an acceptable approach? For some reason, it gives me that "sketchy feeling". So I wanted to make sure.

For example:

```
    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp(){
         appointment = new Appointment("CO","Live & Die",
                "10/21/1999 18:00", "10/21/2099 00:00");
    }

    @Test
    public void addAppointmentMethodIncrementsTheNumOfSavedAppointments(){
        AppointmentBook appointmentBook = new AppointmentBook();
        assertEquals(0, appointmentBook.currentNumOfAppointments());
        appointmentBook.addAppointment(appointment);
        assertEquals(1, appointmentBook.currentNumOfAppointments());
    }

    @Test
    public void addAppointmentMethodSavesTheAppointmentInTheList(){
        AppointmentBook appointmentBook = new AppointmentBook();
        appointmentBook.addAppointment(appointment);
        boolean result = appointmentBook.checkIfAppointmentAlreadyExists(appointment);
        assertEquals(true,result);
    }
```

I am not 'too bothered' by the first test method, but I am unsure about the second one.

- Would you say the `addAppointment()` method is well tested in this
  case?
- or Am I actually testing `checkIfAppointmentAlreadyExists()` method ?
- Could a test method actually test both and still be considered an acceptable unit
  test ?

Here is the code I am trying to test, for reference

```
public class AppointmentBook {
    ArrayList<Appointment> allAppointments = null;

    public AppointmentBook(){
        allAppointments = new ArrayList<Appointment>();
    }

    public int currentNumOfAppointments() {
        return this.allAppointments.size();
    }


    public void addAppointment(Appointment appointment) {
        this.allAppointments.add(appointment);
    }

    public boolean checkIfAppointmentAlreadyExists(Appointment appointment) {
        return this.allAppointments.contains(appointment);
    }
}
```

Comment: we know nothing about the code you are trying to test, or the context of said code, yet you want us to say whether or not your tests are good?

Comment: And also, when you want to assert boolean values, use `assertTrue` and `assertFalse`. In your case: `assertTrue(appointmentBook.checkIfAppointmentAlreadyExists(appointment);`

Comment: @Stultuske I was trying tdd, so I hadn't yet written the actual source code, but it is now posted.

Comment: @C.O. you understand your class is going to throw massive NullPointerExceptions? Seeing as your addAppointment method only does one thing, and does the same thing in each case, one test for this method should be sufficient

Comment: I would see it that way that to properly test `checkIfAppointmentAlreadyExists` you need a setup which is done by adding an appointment via  `appointmentBook.addAppointment(appointment);` - so the (redundant) call to the "add" method is used for actual testing in the first test and as a setup for another test in the second test.

Comment: @Stultuske My Bad, the constructor should've initialized the allAppointments. I think there is no more null pointer dereferencing(I edited it) ? My main question is whether it is okay to use methods from the same class to test the method. Specifically second test method, can I assume both `addAppointment` and `checkIfAppointmentAlreadyExists` are tested in one single method ? Is it a bad practice or does it really matter?

Comment: you can keep several test methods if you want, but you can just as easily put all the asserts in one test method. But if it's possible the code of your class might change so that you'll get different scenario's, you may want to keep them separated

Comment: But to expand more on the topic of unit testing - your class is merely a wrapper of `ArrayList` so you basically test the functionality of `ArrayList` which is not good practice at all if you haven't written the code for `ArrayList` by yourself.

Comment: @Smutje Thanks. The class will grow. But on that issue...Even if it grows with methods that have more logic in them, should I still avoid testing methods that pretty much ask another class (`ArrayList`) to do the work ? In the end, the number of entries in the `allAppointments` is an important message, I want it to be encapsulated, and I have always been told to keep it as simple as possible. Would you suggest public methods like this to be not tested ?

Comment: I believe you misunderstood how unittesting works. The unit in this case *is the class*, not just a single method. When you have a unit to be tested you should have (at least in your head) a clear *contract* on how it should behave. For example one contract can be that, given an appointment `x` the call `checkIfAppointmentAlreadyExists(x)` shall return true if and only if `addAppointment(x)` was called prior to that call. So you can do two tests to check the two directions of the *if only if*. You repeat with all other properties you want your class to have and you are done.

Comment: BTW: `checkIfAppointmentAlreadyExists` is a terrible name. Predicates (i.e. methods returning boolean) should really all start with `is`/`has`/similar verb... they should read like a question not an order. I'd expect a method starting with `check` to return `void` and throw an exception if some condition is not met...

Comment: For an answer to a similar question, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/53430815/5747415.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is totally okay to include multiple methods in a single test case as long as they belong to the same class. Because the smallest unit is **Class** and not a **method()**. And it is Unit test case.

In the second test case you are verifying both `addAppointment` and `checkIfAppointmentAlreadyExists` methods. It is covering two behavior at the same time which is a good practice in my view.